# How to manage (init\start\restart\create schema) my postgreSQL server when running on a single machine with a simple desktop c# app?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, database-administration, npgsql

I want to use postgreSQL in my C# desktop application to save data on the same machine. I have little experience with DB in general and I'm trying to understand what are the best practices to handle the db server. Should my application installer supposed to create and start the db backend service? or should my application run it in start up? how to restart it if it crashes? when do i define the DB schema (all tables) - from the application or as a part of installation?

I'm using Npgsql on my client side without EF. In the past I worked with SQLite but since it dosent support concurrency I thought about moving to postgresql.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you answered your own question when you mentioned concurrent access. If the database is shared between multiple users then it should probably not be considered part of the app, as it is likely to be on a shared server. Often installers assume that a database exists and prompt for a connection, and then create the schema if it doesnt exist. The rest of the admin I would leave to the database admin console.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Sqlite, PostgreSQL generally runs as a separate service on your machine. It is started when your operating system boots and is always running, so your application never has to start it up or shut it down.

If you're looking for options for distributing PostgreSQL as part of your own applications, so that users don't have to install it separately, that should be possible but I don't know of specific options.

Finally, creating the database and schema is typically something your application manages when it starts up. For example, it could check if the schema has already been created (e.g. by checking for the existence of a specific table) and create it if not. There are various ways to manage this kind of thing, but more detail about your scenario would be necessary.